# Is XSS input a threat if ONLY the same user will see it?

Tags: php, security, xss, user-input

What exactly can a malicious user gain if the XSS input he enters will be viewed only by him? Is there anything he can gain?

I understand how XSS is a problem when the malicious user input will be viewed by all site users. But if each user view only his own input, his malicious input will be viewed only by him, so my questions:

- can this affect other users indirectly in some way?
- what can he gain from this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What an attacker can gain with viewing that the xss attack vector he found works, is just that :-) But! Then he can use that attack vector, and there are several ways to do that.

If it's a non-persistent XSS vulnerability (aka reflected), then probably by sending a link (most probably obfuscated via a urlshortener) to potential victims.
If it's a persistent XSS vulnerability (i.e. stored as a comment like the one I'm writing now), then he would just make his post and wait.

Now, what he can gain is a big talk. Just think what you could do if you could inject a script tag into a web page. You could then load a whole javascript file from your server.

The malicious code would then steal some cookies perhaps (if those are not set [httponly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)) and immediately post them via ajax to a backend application..which would probably notify the attacker and who knows..those cookies might be enough to login into that website as the victim.

Well..there are many things an attacker can do..so please eliminate all XSS vulnerabilities you might have.

XSS vulnerabilities mainly take advantage of the trust people have in other websites.
Don't underestimate the [XSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSRF) vulnerabilities which depend on the trust a website has on your browser (another big talk), and Sql Injection attacks.

A few tips (I'm sure you know all about it but for the sake of completeness:

- set httponly in cookies you use to authenticate users
- use htmlentities when printing user input back to your output
- use mysql_real_escape_string before storing user input into your db
- do not perform critical actions (i.e. save/delete/modify articles) using GET requests..use POST for those (xsrf).

Good luck!

UPDATE:

A few tools that can help:

- Chrome plugin : Websecurify
- Firefox Plugin: xss-me
- Windows App: NetSparker Community Edition (free)
- X-platrofm: **SkipFish** , wapiti
- Nessus

(I recommend SkipFish)

Answer (score 2):

I guess not, but this isn't an A/B thing.  Who knows WHAT the "script" part of that "XSS" does.  Maybe the attacker found a vulnerability in your AJAX/javascript, and he is using an XSS-type attack to get a toolkit on your host.  Again, we can speculate about what harm can befall from injection-type attacks all day, the bottom line is that if you can secure against it, do so.  Every trick we can think of here is going to be one trick short of the list that an attacker is using.

Prepare for what you can predict, defend against the known.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it definitely is. The injection could be initiated by a third party as is the case with [reflected XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)#Reflected_XSS_Attacks).

Answer (score 2):

+1 on what @Gumbo pointed out - reflected XSS, but also consider the scenario where a user's account is compromised, and the attacker provides malicious input that will be given back to the (legitimate) user when he or she returns to the site.

Just another potential attack vector ...

Answer (score 1):

As an immediate threat... Probably nothing, since they can't accomplish anything they couldn't do more easily in a direct fashion.

But it should be fixed anyway, since it is possible that a few months down the line requirements change or a new developer re-purposes the same code and then you've got a real problem.

Comment: @0xAli He's not talking about redirections. He just said "in a direct fashion"

Comment: @0xAli: What I mean is that if the user injects javascript code that only he can see while logged on as himself, then what's the point? He can run arbitrary javascript on his own computer *anyway* on any site at all, using browser tools.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking:

1. Can reflected (XSS) code have
   an effect on other visitors prior to
   distributing the link - i.e. during testing

   and
2. What advantage such testing may 
   achieve for the malicious user

If I'm reading you correctly, my answer would be as follows:

1. XSS is about running client-side
   code - usually JavaScript - in an
   unsuspecting user's  browser and
   will have [no effect on other users](http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html#command)
   beyond what is achieved either by
   distributing it via a link,
   persuading a user to enter it
   directly or finding a way for it to
   persist on a given page.

   If you are asking whether it could
   cause some form of command execution
   on the server, that would be [code
   injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) or command injection rather
   than XSS; the malicious user would
   either need to be fortunate enough
   to discover the site uses
   Server-side JavaScript or be bad
   enough at coding that they're
   actually doing something entirely
   different to what they thought!

   Either way, this would require the
   site to be vulnerable to this form
   of injection and is beyond the scope
   of what XSS is about.
2. If we're talking XSS, testing allows
   the malicious user to properly craft
   their final code / link so it is
   as covert as possible and does
   whatever evil deed they intend it
   to.

   Unless someone or some system is
   keeping a watchful eye on the logs
   for e.g. multiple strange HTTP requests,
   the malicious user will be able to
   perfect their exploit so that when
   their tweet / email / whatever goes
   viral it has the desired effect.

HTH